# Where does Firefox store a file downloaded via "open with"

Tags: firefox, opensuse

By mistake I chose the option of "open with" instead of "save file" downloading a somewhat large file (around 3GB, but my max download speed is 350KB/s..). However, I didn't do any action when the download finished...

Is the file stored somewhere? Or upon shutting down the system the file was removed? I don't see it's in `/tmp` (the directory doesn't auto-clean-up).

My system is OpenSUSE Leap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally by default 11.1 and newer erase the /tmp and temporary user files once the system is shut-down. It's for security reasons and drive space.

/tmp would be where it is. I would try `ls -a` in your terminal and see if it's there. If not, it was deleted upon shutdown.